# DART: Canvas: Cross browser setLineDash (Firefox 18.0.1)

Tags: dart

`context.setLineDash()` works in Chrome, but in FireFox 18.0.1 results in

> TypeError: this.setLineDash is not a function

deep in the *bootstrap.dart.js* file.

Even if I use this function

```dart
void setLineDashCatch(var ctx,var param) {
  try {
    ctx.setLineDash(param);
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    log('SetLineDash exception');
  }
}
```

The exception is not caught, and the method is aborted.

What is the best way to avoid the method being aborted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get the log because it is not an `Exception` that is thrown. It is rather a `NoSuchMethodError`. The following code should work :

```dart
void setLineDashCatch(var ctx,var param) {
  try {
    ctx.setLineDash(param);
  } on NoSuchMethodError catch (e) {
    print('SetLineDash exception');
  }
}
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks!  I see I had foolishly(?) assumed that Exception was the parent of anything that gets thrown...